# Record and replay of GWT site using imacros is not working

Tags: firefox, gwt, plugins, smartgwt, imacros

Hope anyone has come across this. I have been using imacros plugin to record/replay web pages on firefox.  It works very well except for GWT pages. For a GWT and smart gwt based webpage, imacros simply clicks on the row and does nothing.

Any suggestions or alternatives would be very helpful.

update: also tried dejaclick plugin for firefox which seems to work partially.

Thanks
San

Comment: Selenium is the tool of choice for gwt apps. Refer official gwt survey report https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/the-future-of-gwt-report-2012 . Also recorded test cases are always flaky on web.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Selenium if you are trying to automate testing. It also comes with a simple record/play firefox plugin.

Selenium Firefox plugin - http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/

Selenium 2 Driver by coding sample  - http://c.gwt-examples.com/home/testing/selenium-testing